# How to show that $A_h$ $\gamma$-converges to $A$ iff $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{|f|_{L^2}\leq 1}\|R_h(f)-R(f)\| = 0. $

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

I am reading a paper by Butazzo, Dal Maso. Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set in $\mathcal{R}^n$. Let $A_h$, $A$ $\subset \Omega$ be (quasi-)open. Consider the following two PDEs with Dirichlet boundary condition.
\begin{align}
-\Delta u_h &= f, \text{in }A_h 
\end{align}\begin{align}
-\Delta u &= f, \text{ in A}\end{align}

Define the resolvant operator $R_h: f\mapsto u_h$, $R: f\mapsto u$.
Butazzo and Dal Maso claimed that $A_h$ $\gamma$-converges to $A$ iff
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup_{|f|_{L^2}\leq 1}\|R_h(f)-R(f)\| = 0. $$

I am most interested in the if direction. By the definition of $\gamma$-convergence, we know that $u_h \rightarrow u$ in $H^1_0$. I wonder how to go from here to the uniform operator topology?

In the paper, it is mentioned that $R_h$ is equi-continuous family (do they mean $R_h(f)$?) from $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ to $H^1_0(\Omega)$ and that $L^2(\Omega)$ is compact in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$. I am not following how those two condition comes in play here. Does equicontinuous family of operators on a compact set has some special properties probably?

Thank you!

Comment: For real-valued functions, equicontinuity of a family of functions on a compact set gives precompactness of the family in the topology of uniform convergence, by Arzela-Ascoli. I'm not sure how this generalizes to this case but I suspect that's what's going on.